# JAVA GUI: Can someone help me check why my button doesn't respond to it being clicked?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

i'm new to JAVA GUI and I have just started to learn, I started writing this simple authentication box and i am not sure why my "fogotpassword" button doesn't respond in line                 "else if (event.getSource()==forgotpassword)" in the method thehandler. Nothing happens when i click it. The System.out.println("s") under it doesn't print.

Help would be very appreciated :). Have a good day.

```
public class miniProject extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField UsernameBox;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JButton forgotpassword;
    private JButton buttonLogin; 

public miniProject()
{
    super("Login Page");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2,5,10));
    setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    JLabel username = new JLabel("                          Username:");
    //username.setEditable(false);
    add(username);

    UsernameBox = new JTextField(10);
    add(UsernameBox);

    //item3.setEditable(false);
    JLabel passowrd = new JLabel("                          Password:");
    add(passowrd);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
    add(passwordField);

    buttonLogin = new JButton("Login");
    add(buttonLogin);

    forgotpassword = new JButton("Forgot My Password");
    add(forgotpassword);

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    UsernameBox.addActionListener(handler);
    passwordField.addActionListener(handler);
    buttonLogin.addActionListener(handler);
    forgotpassword.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class thehandler implements ActionListener
{
    int i =5;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String string = "";
        if (event.getSource()== passwordField || event.getSource()== UsernameBox ||event.getSource()==buttonLogin)
        {
            String password="";
            if(passwordField.getPassword().length != 0 && UsernameBox.getText().length()!=0 )
            {
                for (char a :passwordField.getPassword())
                {
                    password +=a;
                }
                password = password.trim();
                if (password.equals("kyle") && UsernameBox.getText().equals("marcus"))
                {
                    string = String.format("Welcome Back!", event.getActionCommand());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
                }
                else 
                {
                    string = String.format("Incorrect Password\n "+i+" more attempts remaining until your account is locked", event.getActionCommand());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            else if (event.getSource()==forgotpassword)
            {
                System.out.println("s");
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email");
                if (input.length()!=0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, "Check your email to reset password!", "Password Reset",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            else if (passwordField.getPassword().length == 0)
            {
                string = String.format("You didn't enter your password!",event.getActionCommand());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
            }
            else if (UsernameBox.getText().length()==0)
            {
                string = String.format("You didn't enter your username!",event.getActionCommand());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems not to work as intended, because the `if` in the second line of your `actionPerformed` Method does not contain a condition for checking, if the forgotpassword Button is the event source. You have to either add this check to the outer if or move the `else if (event.getSource()==forgotpassword)` outside of this outer if.